# How to retrive last 32 bits from byteArray in java?

Tags: java, byte

Hi I am struggling to retrieve last 32 bits/4bytes from byte Array. Please anyone help me.

Example:

```
byte[] b = scientificDatas;//1024bits
```

I want to retrieve last 32 bits from 'b'. I tried with shift operator. its not working properly.
Please anyone help me.

Comment: just take read byte from index 0-3

Comment: @JigarJoshi is that the definition of "last"? :)

Comment: dint get u.Could u please give me an example

Comment: @JigrJoshi You're still back to front. Bytes 0..3 would normally be the most significant.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could copy a range of the original array:

```
    byte[] result = Arrays.copyOfRange(b, b.length - 4, b.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `DataInputStream:`

```
DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(scientificDatas));
din.seek(1024/8-4);
int integer = din.readInt();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the array will contain 1024 bits (128 bytes), it's as trivial as indexing the array appropriately:

```
byte[] last4bytes = new byte[4]{b[124], b[125], b[126], b[127]};
```

If you don't know the length of the array, use the `length` field:

```
 byte[] last4bytes = new byte[4]{b[b.length-4], b[b.length-3], b[b.length-2], b[b.length-1]};
```